# PHP Google App Engine with SESSION,COOKIES

Tags: php, forms, google-app-engine, session, cookies

I`m just starting a project with google app engine using PHP.

Something very strange appears today..

Simple code:

```
    session_start();
if ($_COOKIE['test'] == 1) {
    setcookie('test', 2);
} elseif ($_COOKIE['test'] == 2) {
    setcookie('test', 3);
} elseif ($_COOKIE['test'] == 3) {
    setcookie('test', 4);
} elseif ($_COOKIE['test'] == 4) {
    setcookie('test', 1);
}



echo $_COOKIE['test'];
exit;
```

Which on the local machine works like :
1 -> refresh -> 2 -> refresh -> 3 -> refresh -> 4 -> refresh -> 1 and so on...

However on the google app engine it works like :
2 -> refresh -> 4 -> refresh -> 2 -> refresh -> 4.... and so on.

With this code

```
    <?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['test'] == 1){
    $_SESSION['test'] = 2;
}else{
    $_SESSION['test'] = 1;
}



echo $_SESSION['test'];exit;
?>
```

On the local server I get - > 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2....
On the google app engine I get -> 2 -> 2 -> 2....

Like always refreshing two times.

With the $_POST and $_GET , I don`t have any problem.

```
    <?php $post = $_POST['test'];
$post = $post + 1;
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="<?= $post ?>">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Always getting +1

I`m pretty confused...
Tried on the local machine with python 2.7,also on the google app engine servers...

Comment: Did you test for === '1' (ie actually is a string)?

Comment: Same story...
However if I press the refresh button 2 times really quickly its refreshed 3 times,not 4...
If I start clicking really fast.. then its working like it should ..

Comment: Just find out that the problem is only with google chrome...
On IE,Opera,Firefox there`s absolutely no problem!

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that this was a tricky one.

I wouldn't blame Chrome for this bug, but I believe that the creators of php-sdk for App Engine should provide more clear documentation about their routing logic.

It happens because Chrome is trying to load favicon.ico and by default App Engine routes this file to your home page, so you end up running your home page twice without even realizing it.

The solution is to add this to your app.yaml file:

```
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: static/images/favicon\.ico
```

Even if you don't actually have a favicon, it's better to get a 404 for the favicon than to reload your home page.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your php.ini variables_order = "GPCS".
I tested your code bit modified on both local development and production environment at Google App Engine, they both behave the same, loop 1, 2, 3, 4 for cookies and 1, 2 for session.

However I modified your code a little since you do not have to start session to use cookies in first place, but with you code "if" conditions the way you do, you have to pre set up first cookie setcookie('test', 1), since it does not exist originally when you start the script.

Keep in mind the $_COOKIE will not read the value you setup with setcookie until next page refresh Heres my test script:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['test']) || !in_array($_COOKIE['test'], array(1,2,3,4)) ) {
    setcookie('test', 1);
} elseif ($_COOKIE['test'] == 1) {
    setcookie('test', 2);
} elseif ($_COOKIE['test'] == 2) {
    setcookie('test', 3);
} elseif ($_COOKIE['test'] == 3) {
    setcookie('test', 4);
} elseif ($_COOKIE['test'] == 4) {
    setcookie('test', 1);
}

session_start();

if($_SESSION['test'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['test'] = 2;
}else{
    $_SESSION['test'] = 1;
}

printf("cookie: %s <br>\n session: %s <br>\n", $_COOKIE['test'], $_SESSION['test']);
exit;
```

Comment: Same story...
Returning - cookie: 3 
session: 2 
refresh
cookie: 1 
session: 2 
refresh
cookie: 3 
session: 2

Comment: maybe try posting your phpinfo() from Google App Engine we can compare. Also you may wanna inspect the code for header request response to see what exactly is going on. Chrome and Firefox has good debug developer console.